# Function keeps on rendering when I try to add to a value to the sum. create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a function in which when a user clicks the add button `className = "addButton"` ; they will add the price value which is obtained from the .json that was fetched in the parent class `this.props.products`.

My problem is > When I try to render the ProductSquare component which contains the add button and a few other things related to the product, it will render in a infinite loop.

I am also selectivly targeting products that have the unique `product._id`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

//css classes
import "./cssForComponents/ProductSquare.css";
import AddButton from "./addButton.js";

class ProductSquare extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: true,
      sum: 0
    };

    this.onClickHandlerForAdd = this.onClickHandlerForAdd.bind(this);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  onClickHandlerForAdd(price) {
    this.setState({ sum: price });
  }

  getData() {
    return this.props.products.map(
      (product) =>
        product._id === "5b77587c570ee12e768704da" ? ( 
          <div className="ProductSquare" key={product.index}>
            <button
              className="AddButton"
              onClick={this.onClickHandlerForAdd(product.price)}
            >
              {product.price}
            </button>

            <button className="InfoButton">{product.about}</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          console.log("Results were not loaded")
        )
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.sum);

    return this.getData();
  }
}

export default ProductSquare;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your onClick handler is actually being *called* when you are doing the render; hence the state is changing, hence another render etc. It should be:

```
onClick={() => this.onClickHandlerForAdd(product.price)}
```

That way the onClick handler is registering a function *to be called when clicked*

Comment: this solved the issue, so it is rendering even if I am not clicking the button. With your solution the function only get called when I click? So now I see very little use in just using  `this.onClickHandlerForAdd(product.price)}`  during onClick.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using arrow functions in the render method. To have a good understanding why, you can refer this article.

[Why arrow functions are problematic inside render?](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36)

One way to to do this is to use a closure for the clickHandlers. You can modify your existing functions as below.

<strike>this.onClickHandlerForAdd = this.onClickHandlerForAdd.bind(this);</strike>

<strike>this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);</strike>

```
onClickHandlerForAdd = price => () => {
    this.setState({ sum: price });
}
```

and

```
getData = () => {
    return this.props.products.map(
        (product) =>
        product._id === "5b77587c570ee12e768704da" ? ( 
            <div className="ProductSquare" key={product.index}>
            <button
                className="AddButton"
                onClick={this.onClickHandlerForAdd(product.price)}
            >
                {product.price}
            </button>

            <button className="InfoButton">{product.about}</button>
            </div>
        ) : (
            console.log("Results were not loaded")
        )
    );
}
```